# Chasing Pointers Approach Fails

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I am trying to modify a char array ("1,204,342,544") to remove all commas in a most efficient way. I am using chasing pointers approach for this problem. I have implemented the solution in C++, but my code seems to fail. I need some help in finding/correcting my mistake. Also please suggest if there are better (more efficient methods) to implement the same solution.

I know it's really simple in Python!.

```
arr = "1,234,34,54"
print arr.replace(',','')
```

In C ++ using chasing pointers (Efficient way)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


char* removeCommas(char* arr) {
    char *curr = arr; // pointer to current position
    char *tail = arr; // tail pointer

    while (curr) {
        if (*curr != ',') {
            if (curr != tail) {
                *tail = *curr;
            }
            curr ++;
            tail ++;
        }
        else {
            curr ++;
        }
    }
    *tail = '\0';
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    char arr[] = "1,204,342,544";    
    removeCommas(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string s = "1,204,342,544";
s.erase( remove( s.begin(), s.end(), ',' ), s.end() );
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there are other problems, but the first thing that stands out is this:

```
while (curr)
```

Since I don't see any assignment to `NULL` or `nullptr` anywhere in the code, I don't see how that can possibly be right.  So I assume you probably meant to check for a null character, not a null pointer.

```
while (*curr)
```

Comment: Thanks! i was a bit careless. Can you suggest any other efficient methods.

Comment: @ArunprasathShankar: See Alf's answer.  Or luksy's.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* removeCommas(char* arr) {
        char *curr = arr; // pointer to current position
        char *tail = arr; // tail pointer

        while(1){
                switch(*tail=*curr++){
                        case '\0':
                                return arr;
                        case  ',':
                                continue;
                        default:
                                tail++;
                }
        }
}
```